# Getting the specific index number of every group

Tags: pandas

In this sample dataframe df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

i = ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant'] * 3
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(9, 4), index=i, 
columns=list('ABCD')).sort_index()
```

What is the quickest way to get the 2nd row of each animal as a dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html).  If an animal has only a single row, no result will be returned.

> **`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth(n, dropna=None)`**
>
> Take the nth row from each group if n is an int, or a subset of rows if n is a list of ints.

```
df.groupby(level=0).nth(1)
```

```
                 A         B         C         D
cat      -2.189615 -0.527398  0.786284  1.442453
dog       2.190704  0.607252  0.071074 -1.622508
elephant -2.536345  0.228888  0.716221  0.472490
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group the data by index and get elements at index 1 (second row) for each group

```
new_df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1, :])

            A           B           C           D
cat         0.089608    -1.181394   -0.149988   -1.634295
dog         0.002782    1.620430    0.622397    0.058401
elephant    1.022441    -2.185710   0.854900    0.979411
```

If you expect any group with single value in your dataframe, you can build in that condition

```
new_df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1, :] if len(x) > 1 else None).dropna()
```

Comment: +1 I like this because it's far easier to return only the first row if there aren't 2 rows with the `if else`